# Setup IIS 6/7 to passthrough to Glassfish v2.x

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, glassfish, passthrough

I need to setup IIS 6 and 7 to pass all request to Glassfish v2.x. Is there a simple tutorial that will get this interaction between IIS and Glassfish working?

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish supports ajp, so you could use the isapi_redirect.dll from the apache tomcat connectors project to forward all requests.  I wrote a starter HOWTO but being new to ServerFault, I don't know if it is tacky to link to one's own sites.  Google "howto isapi_redirect.dll" and mine is the fourth result.